# Dynamic Combobox Jquery Codeigniter Using Radio Button

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

I have condition where I must load different data from database to populate the combobox. The combobox depends on radio button selection.

[image]

If I select jababeka plan, it loads jababeka value, if I select MM2100 plan is loads MM2100 plan, and continue onwards.

Is it possible? any one can show me how?

thanks before.

Comment: Please update your post with code so can get idea.

Comment: but its just html code, i didnt make any server side script.

Comment: This will require using ajax call to fill after click or (if the combobox options will be static) pre-generated array of options for combobox.

Comment: @Michał great, but how with dynamic combobox depend radio select?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your markup looks similar to this:

```
<form action="">
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="1">op1</input>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="2">op2</input>
    <select id="options"></select>
</form>
```

You can use jQuery to check selected option in radio boxes and relatively set `<select>` content:

```
var op1 = ["lorem", "ipsum"];
var op2 = ["dolor", "sit", "amet"];

function fillSelect(data) {
    $("#options").children("option").remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('<option/>').val(data[i]).html(data[i])
        .appendTo('#options');
    }
}

$("input[name=a]").click(function () {
    if($(this).val() == 1)
        fillSelect(op1);
    else
        fillSelect(op2);
});
```

Working example: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bkzoa5tp/)

Comment: @Dwi Abriyanto is this what you needed?